# Cannot access android.support.v7.widget.recyclerview.adapter

Tags: android

I developed codes with MVP(Model View Presenter) pattern, in the View I create a `RecyclerViewAdapter` and offer it in this method :

```
public class MVPView extends ... implements...  {

    //ps:RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerViewAdapter 
    private RecyclerAdapter<User> mAdapter;

    ......        

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter<User> getRecyclerAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }
}
```

But when I want to get this Adapter and use it in Presenter, Android Studio 3.0 IDE show this error:

Error Image:

[image]

**ps:** The method `getView()` returns the object `MyView`.

After that I tried to use this code in `MyView`, it worked. So, I don't know why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.
The reason is that I put the RecyclerAdapter in module A and Presenter in module B, I forget to compile RecyclerView in module B.
Sry, I asked a stupid question.